# android change textview drowabletop by java activity

Tags: android, textview

i have tetview

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/new" />
```

and i want to change the `drawableTop` by java activity, how please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, assign an id your TextView. Then you can use [`setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to change the drwables of the TextView in your Activity:

```
Textview t = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView);
t.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (0,R.drawable.new,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
//to is the drawable
  textView.setCompoundDrawables(null, top, null, null);
```